# Cannot get XPath to work with unnamed namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

The XML (fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetXMLResponse xmlns="http://sitecore.net/visual/">
<GetXMLResult>
<sitecore xmlns="">
<status>ok</status>
```

The code (fragment):

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(template.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsManager.PushScope();

XmlNode sitecoreRoot = template.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[namespace-uri()='http://sitecore.net/visual/' and local-name()='GetXMLResponse']", nsManager);

string status = sitecoreRoot.SelectSingleNode("/GetXMLResult/sitecore/status").Value;
```

sitecoreRoot element returns the correct node.  However the XPath to get the status always returns null, even though the siteCoreRoot.OuterXMl property shows the element is present.

The only thing I can think of is the line:

```
<sitecore xmlns="">
```

is throwing off the XPath

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(cd.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("sp", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        ns.AddNamespace("sc", "http://sitecore.net/visual/");
        XmlNode sitecoreRoot = cd.SelectSingleNode("//sp:Envelope/sp:Body/sc:GetXMLResponse/sc:GetXMLResult/sitecore/status", ns);
var status = sitecoreRoot.InnerText;
```

May help you?

Comment: I had actually tried that solution before with no luck.  However, your answer did spur me on to answer my own question.  The "gotcha" is the node: <sitecore xmlns="">.  It seem like the empty xmlns attrubute "turns off" the namespace.  So the working XPath looks like:   /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:GetXMLResponse/ns:GetXMLResult/sitecore/status

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the status node, you can try [this xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) and the following XPath.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
XElement status = root.XPathElement("//status");
```

The library handles doing the namespace for you.